# Should I send a resume before the second interview with a new person?

Tags: resume, interviewing

I have applied for a job. A contact person was a group leader. I sent him my resume and a cover letter. Later, I had a phone interview with him. Now they want me to have the second phone interview with a CTO.

Is it a good idea to send him my resume before the interview?

Nobody told me his email, but it's easy to find it.
In my opinion, this could look like I really care about the interview. On the other hand, next interviewer should definitely have my resume from the previous one and my email could look stupid.

Comment: I agree with the top voted answer (don't send, it's on them to be prepared in their hiring system) but note that in other situations you might need to be prepared for an unexpected roadbump - for instance your resume may have been altered by a recruiter, or they got it from monster.com and they might not have the resume you think they have.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like you said, he probably already got your resume from the previous interviewer. Personally, I think it would seem weird to send him your resume because:

- They did not ask you to send him your resume
- They did not give you the interviewers e-mail address, so it might seem stalker-ish that you are e-mailing him.

Comment: But bring a few hard copy ones to the interview just in case.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't send your resume a second time. Like you said, there's no need to. Going into the next phone interview, the second interviewer should have at least your resume, if not any notes from any previous interviews. You should only resend your resume to a company for the same position if you are asked to.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to ask before the interview actually starts (i.e. they call, introduce themselves, you introduce yourself, and then immediately before any discussion begins) ask if they have a copy of your resume, and if they do not, inquire if they'd like you to email it to them real fast (i'm assuming you're at a computer when this occurs).

Comment: Just give them a hard copy...This only requires hands.

Comment: @Ramhound you should read the question.  this is a phone interview that's being discussed...

Answer (score 1):

Take a copy of your resume with you to the interview. I give the CTO a 50/50 chance of even looking at your resume beforehand. Save them some face by offering a "cleaner" copy.

You're better off getting his/her business card and sending a thank you email after the interview.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's reasonable to expect the CTO to have received your resume via his internal channels.  Thus, unless you've been asked for it, sending it to him/her before this second interview seems unnecessary and may make you look over-anxious.

There is one exception I'd like to note:  You don't say how long it has been since the first interview and the second one.  Hopefully, not much time has elapsed.  However, sometimes these things take time; if several weeks (or a few months) have elapsed, and you've picked up new experience you'd like to highlight, then sending an updated resume could be a good idea.

While the situation is different, a few years ago I submitted my resume to a company which contacted me a few months later about a different job than the one I'd originally inquired about.  In that time, I had picked up some experience which was directly relevant to the new job, so I submitted a new resume and that helped me get the job.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send it. Leave it to their internal process to pass the resume along to the CTO. Take a copy with you for the interview, but don't send it beforehand. It also could make you look a little "too eager" (desperate or inexperienced in these matters), which is the *kiss of death* for you as a potential candidate. What I mean by this, is: a desperate candidate does not earn respect and often gets the short end of the stick during salary negotiations.